# Placeholders are submitted as values using serialize and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, serialization

I have a form:

```
<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  

    <input type="text" name="name" class="button-size-1"  placeholder="*Name">

    <input type="text" name="email" class="button-size-1"  placeholder="*Email">

    ..
</form>
```

I send the values of this form to a PHP file, Using the following code:

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "/process.php",
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);   
    },
});
```

When I print the posted data, I find the following instead of the actual values:

```
Array
(
    [name] => *Name
    [email] => *Email
)
```

There is a jQuery code that may be causing this issue:

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {         
    var input = $(this);          
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {         
        input.val('');          
        input.removeClass('placeholder');         
    }       
}).blur(function() {          
    var input = $(this);          
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder'))     {            
        input.addClass('placeholder');          
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));         
    }       
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {         
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {         
        var input = $(this);            
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {           
            input.val('');          
        }         
    })      
});
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: First add the value attribute to your inputs as this may prevent the unwanted side-effects that you are getting. Secondly, you could probably drop all of the jQuery code for managing the placeholder text as the modern browsers already support this feature.

Comment: Don't do this: `input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));`

Comment: What excatly are you trying to do with the jquery code and the placeholders?

Comment: @K.D, I don't know I'm just editing the page, I didn't add this part

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the values of the inputs to placeholders. It is okay to add/remove the placeholder class, but don't change its values. The placeholder is the text that you show when there is no value in the input and it is something completely different from the value. So do something like this:

```
$('form input').focus(function() {         
    var input = $(this);          
    if (!input.val()) {         
        input.addClass('placeholder');         
    }       
}).blur(function() {          
    var input = $(this);          
    if (!input.val())     {            
        input.removeClass('placeholder');          
    }       
}).blur();
```